# How to nest OR statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nested-statement

Currently I am creating a filemanager.

What I want is to check if the user has selected a video file. The file can be `mov`, `f4v`, `flv`, `mp4` and `swf`.

I want to check if my var `ext` is one of these.

What I have is:

```
if(ext == ('mov' || 'f4v' || 'flv' || 'mp4' || 'swf'))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get this working. I don't want to use a switch because I will get a lot of cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to explicitly compare the variable against each of those values.

```
if( ext === 'mov' || ext === 'f4v' || ... ) { 
}
```

..but, *RegExp* to the rescue, we can go like

```
if( /mov|f4v|flv|mp4|swf/.test( ext ) ) { 
}
```

Comment: The RegExp save me this time (again). I had to remove the first `|` for this `/mov|f4v|flv|mp4|swf/`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to split them up, like so:

```
if(ext === "mov" || ext === "f4v" || ext === "flv" || ext === "mp4" || ext === "swf")
{
    // do stuff
}
```

you could also consider putting all the different extension in an array and checking whether ext exists in that array

Answer (score 2):

Kinda nice way is this:

```
var exts = {
     "mov" : null,
     "f4v" : null,
     "flv" : null,
     "mp4" : null,
     "swf" : null,
}

if(ext in exts){
    // world peace
}
```