# JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there anyway to do this:

```
    if (document.getElementById("x").value == 2 || document.getElementById("x").value == 3) {
         //Do somthing
    }
```

# Can I make it simple in some kind a way like this, I tried but it didn't work:

```
    if (document.getElementById("x").value == 2 || 3) {
         //Do somthing
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as an alternative to the other answers, if you don't want to be declaring another variable in that scope for whatever reason:

```
if (["2", "3"].indexOf(document.getElementById("x").value) > -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Please note that older browsers don't support `Array.prototype.indexOf` so you would need to include [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

The way you suggest does not work, as you've realized yourself. The `|| 3` part will always be [truthy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript), and therefor the code within the if-statement would always run.

If you want to make the if-statement more readable, you could keep the value in a variable, and use the variable in the if-statement. Something like this:

```
var xVal = document.getElementById("x").value;
if (xVal == 2 || xVal == 3) {
     //Do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something different:

```
if (document.getElementById("x").value in {2:0,3:0}) {
    //Do something
}
```

Personally I use this for such situations - it's often actually the shortest (especially as the 'ORs' pile up).

Comment: Original answer, but may be difficult to read/understand if you come back to it later, and would also get very messy if you want more values.

Comment: @Kolink well, it depends what you're used to. I personally am comfortable with it and have been using it so.. it's as familiar as anything else.. Also more values is just: {2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}.. etc. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you could get the value before hand, which would make it read clearer

```
var yourValue = document.getElementById("x").value

if (yourValue == 2 || yourValue == 3)
```

Comment: This will always fail, because element values are strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("x").value;

if(myValue == 2 || myValue == 3) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a modern browser:

```
if( [2,3].indexOf(document.getElementById('x').value) > -1)
```

Older versions of IE will need a shim to achieve this. Or you can implement it yourself:

```
function in_array(needle,haystack) {
    var l = haystack.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// ...
if( in_array(document.getElementById('x').value,[2,3])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something when the value is either 2 or 3 , you only have to write

```
if (document.getElementById("x").value == 2 || document.getElementById("x").value == 3) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will help you

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/129/

**Script:**

```
var value = document.getElementById("x").value;
if ((value in [,1,2]))
alert("Do SomeThing");
```

**Full Script:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function check()
{
   var value = document.getElementById("txtin").value;
   if ((value in [,1,2,3]))
     alert("Do SomeThing");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick='check()'>check</a>
    <input type="text" id="txtin"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var x=document.getElementById("x").value;

if (x == 2 || x == 3) {
         //Do somthing
    }
```