# boolean condition verification

Tags: java, python, scala, boolean-expression

I want to do boolean check like this.This doesn't work. But my idea is like this

```
if(num==(1,2,3)){
        println (num)
    }
```

or

```
if(num==(1|2|3)){
        println (num)
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Bad tags, lack of basic knowledge. If you are aiming for java, do check official Java SE documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Comment: The dupe is Javascript, but since it shows the general approach and you tagged spammed your question, it should be fine.

Comment: You shouldn't tag Python and Scala in your question if you are looking for java code.

Answer (score 1):

`num==(1,2,3)` is not a valid expression in Java. (Although in C and C++ it is equivalent to `num == 3`).

You need to write `if (num == 1 || num == 2 || num == 3)`.

If `num` is an integral type, you could use `if (num >= 1 && num <= 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((1 to 3) contains num) {
  print(num)
}
```