# Why does this and/or scenario evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, operators

Why does this return `false`?

```
var flavor = "chocolate";
console.log(flavor == ("vanilla" || "chocolate"));
```

and if I type instead:

```
var flavor = "chocolate";
console.log(flavor == ("vanilla" && "chocolate"));
```

it returns `true`. This doesn't make sense to me because logically, flavor cannot equal both chocolate and vanilla. Can someone help me understand how I should be thinking through this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(flavor == ("vanilla" || "chocolate"))` returns *false* because `("vanilla" || "chocolate")` returns as `"vanilla"`, so you're actually comparing `"chocolate" == "vanilla"`, which returns *false*.

`(flavor == ("vanilla" && "chocolate"))` returns *true* because `("vanilla" && "chocolate")` returns as `"chocolate"`, so `"chocolate" == "chocolate"` obviously returns *true*.

I think what you actually want is `(flavor == "vanilla" || flavor == "chocolate")` and `(flavor == "vanilla" && flavor == "chocolate")`. Give that a try :)