# In JavaScript, how do you check "a" against "b," "c," etc. in a simple manner?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Currently, the only way I know of to do what the title states is by writing the following:

```
var a = 3, b = 5, c = 3;
if (a === b && a === c) {
  // code
}
```

Or by using the ternary operator:

```
(a === b && a === c) ? /* code */ : /* else */
```

Is there a way to check `a` against both `b` and `c`? Something like this perhaps:

```
if (a === (b && c)) {
  // code
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work as intended, which is why I'm asking the question. Any help is appreciated.

This is **not** a duplicate of the other 2 - those two are using the OR operator. I'm asking about the AND operator.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `if (a === b && a === c) {`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Both possible duplicates are asking about the OR operator. I'm asking about the AND operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple case like this? Definitely not. There are some handy little tricks you can use if you build an array, however. For example:

```
var my_array = [3, 5, 3];
if(my_array.every(function(el) {return el == my_array[0];})) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Or you can use arrow function `if (my_array.every(el => el === my_array[0]))`

Comment: @Tomas In modern browsers, definitely. I wanted my solution to account for older browsers for the less fortunate among us. Thank you for providing this alternative solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. That's what you have. Unless you convert it to an Array and test with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

if a,b and c are all numbers then you can do simple maths to check for parity of b and c against a.

**Simply add b and c, divide by 2 to get the average number and use that to compare against a.**

```js
var a = 3, b = 5, c = 3;
  a === (b + c)/2 
  ? console.log('yes')
  : console.log('no')
 
 // console gives "no"
  
var a = 3, b = 3, c = 3;
  a === (b + c)/2 
  ? console.log('yes')
  : console.log('no') 
  
  // console gives "yes"
  
  
  
var a = 3, b = 4, c = 2;
  a === (b + c)/2 
  ? console.log('yes')
  : console.log('no') 
 
 // console gives "yes"
```

Comment: it is not correct for all cases
eg: 
var a = 3, b = 4, c = 2;

a === (b + c)/2
  ? console.log('yes')
  : console.log('no') // gives "yes"

Comment: @AmjadRehmanA - its been a long time since this answer - but it seems to me that your example SHOULD give "yes" as the solution - if a is 3 and b is 4 and c is 2 then a does equal (b + c)/2.... in other words 3 is equal to (4+2)/2 because that equates to (6)/2 or 3... .so the equatino would be is 3 === 3 , which is yes.Answer amended to include your example...