# Small question about google sheet, script editor code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

In a google sheet i use the following code to delete an entire row :

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
  var r = s.getRange('D:D');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='4 - Approved')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

It says that when the text : 4 - approved  is showing in a cell... then he will delete the whole row. That is oke.

But i need a code for the following.

When the text : "4 - approved" or "5 - Good" is in a cel then he need to delete the line, not only with 4 - approved...

Comment: See [Ask] and provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(v[0,i]=='4 - Approved')
```

by

```
if((v[0,i]=='4 - Approved') || (v[0,i]=='5 - Good'))
```

Related

- [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9121395/1595451)