# Best way to compare variable to multiple integers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a game and I have a variable `id`. I need to compare that to multiple integers (lets say 10). I know you can simply use the `||` and do

```
if (id == 1 || id == 2 || id == 3)
```

which is perfectly fine, except in this case, I need to do that 10-15 times. Is there any quicker way to do this (it's the same variable that I'm comparing. Just different numbers).

I don't want an answer requiring a switch statement (which is also almost as much work). And I also don't want an answer using the `||` operator (like I showed in the code above).

Comment: Anoter duplicate: [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array and then validate that id using the function `includes`.

```js
const id = 2;
const array = [1, 2, 3];

if (array.includes(id)) console.log("I'm in!");
```

Comment: This answer is lost here. It should be added to the popular duplicates instead. It was already given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values but not in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

Put the numbers that you want to check against in an array and check if the `id` exists in it using `indexOf` :

```js
const id = 2;
const arr = [1,2,3];

if (arr.indexOf(id) > -1) 
  console.log('it exists');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Array to hold all the values you are comparing `id` against and use `Array#indexOf` to check if `id` is inside the Array.

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];
if(values.indexOf(id)!==-1){
  //id equals one of the elements of the values array
}
```

If you need to know which element `id` is equal to, you can store the index that it was found in the array as and then get the element of the Array at that index.

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];
var index = values.indexOf(id);
if(index!==-1){
  var value = values[index];//this is the value of id
  //id equals one of the elements of the values array
}
```