# Using if statement to filter data with multiple string values

Tags: javascript

Using If statement to filter data with multiple string values

i want to sort the file extension in one line because if i dont do that i have to write multiple lines of code which i think is a waste of time. can i get some help here

```
if (fileExtension === "jpg"||"Jpeg"||"png"||"svg"){
//do something 
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

if have so file extension jpg then its directly switching to else statement and if i give just jpg i.e `if (fileExtension === "jpg")` then the code runs fine i want to use multiple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Comment: `if (["jpg","jpeg","png","svg"].includes(fileExtension.toLower​Case()))` Did you try searching before asking? there are tons of questions like this, having tons of **great** answers to check.

Comment: You can use `.indexOf()` like `if(["jpg","jpeg","png","svg"].indexOf(fileExtension) > -1)`

Answer (score 5):

`"jpg"||"Jpeg"||"png"||"svg"` is an expression which will evaluate to first truthy value. Here `"jpg"` is first truthy value so while whole expression becomes `"jpg"`. See [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)
.

You can store all the values in array and then use `some()` on array and compare it with `fileExtension`

`"Jpeg"` may cause some problem. capital `J`. I would suggest you to change all the values to lower case and then compare inside `some()`

```js
let fileExtension = "svg"

if (["jpg","jpeg","png","svg"].some(x => fileExtension.toLowerCase() === x)){
  console.log("found")
}
else{
  cosnole.log("not found")
}
```

**Note**: You can also use `includes()` in this case. But I would prefer `some()` because it allows user to compare with multiple conditions

Comment: Well done for explaining why the code didn't work. As a side note, I would check for lowercase / uppercase values as an extra feature, since the issue likely would happen with "Jpeg".

Answer (score 3):

Everyone else is using an array, so here's an example with a regex [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)] [[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)] instead:

```js
function testExtension(fileExtension) {
  if (/jpg|jpeg|png|svg/.test(fileExtension.toLowerCase())) {
    console.log(`${fileExtension} found`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${fileExtension} not found`); 
  }
}

testExtension('mpg');
testExtension('jpg');
testExtension('svg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fileExtension === "jpg"|| fileExtension ==="Jpeg" || fileExtension ==="png" || fileExtension ==="svg"){
//do something 
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

you should check each string with the fileExtension.

Comment: I would use `.some` instead of writing a novel ;)

Comment: i too but i thought to explain as simple way for new contributor

Comment: Though your answer solves the issue, I would recommend (even to a new contributor) to show how the problem is solved by providing 'best-practice'- examples/solutions ;)

Comment: so if he/she may be beginner that will go bounce above the head

Comment: Good point - but don't wrongly assume that just because someone is new on SO this person is not familiar to using functions instead of statements/declarations ;)

Comment: every one has different thoughts what i feel right i have done.

Answer (score 0):

Includes can solve your problem.

```
if (["jpg", "Jpeg", "png", "svg"].includes(fileExtension)) {
   //do something 
} else{
   //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) prototype of Array:

```
if (['jpg', 'Jpeg', 'png', 'svg'].includes(fileExtension)) {
    ...
}
```

You can also add toLowerCase(), to be a bit safer:

```
if (['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'svg'].includes(fileExtension.toLower​Case())) {
    ...
}
```

As an alternative (but much less readable) series of OR conditions:

```
if (fileExtension === 'jpg' || fileExtension === 'Jpeg' 
    || fileExtension === 'png' || fileExtension ==='svg'){
```

as you can see it will be less readable, with more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.indexOf()` which returns the item position, if the item doesn't exist it returns `-1`

```
if(["jpg","jpeg","png","svg"].indexOf(fileExtension) > -1){
//do something...
}
```

Another way Using `.filter()`

```
if(["jpg","jpeg","png","Svg"].filter(function(i){return i.toLowerCase() === fileExtension.toLowerCase()}).length == 1){
    //do something...
    }
```