# Discord.js bot looping using || or operator

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am having an issue when I use the or opperator || the bot will send 5 messages at once, and continue to loop. Without using the or operator it works fine. It will also accept some letters like c, or h to start the loop, which is odd.

This is the code it will print out onto the discord.

```
Hello @thehiddencheese! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact @thehiddencheese.
Hello @thehiddencheese's test bot! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact @thehiddencheese.
Hello @thehiddencheese's test bot! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact @thehiddencheese.
Hello @thehiddencheese's test bot! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact @thehiddencheese.
Hello @thehiddencheese's test bot! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact @thehiddencheese.
```

Here is the code

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  let targetMember = message.member.user;
  if (message.content === '!help' || '!command') {
    message.channel.send(
      `Hello ${targetMember}! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact <@248030367666274304>.`
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Replace `if (message.content === '!help' || '!command') {` with `if (message.content === '!help' || message.content ===  '!command') {`

Comment: This fixed it, I'm curious why that is though? Edit: Just seen your post

Comment: I added an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `if (message.content === '!help' || '!command') {` has two blocks: `message.content === '!help'` and `'!command'`. The `||` or operator says: "either of those things should be true".

So it ignores the first block because the second block will always be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

What you're trying to do is this:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  let targetMember = message.member.user;
  if (message.content === '!help' || message.content === '!command') {
    message.channel.send(
      `Hello ${targetMember}! This bot is currently used for testing only. Features will be added in the future, however for more info, please contact <@248030367666274304>.`
    );
  }
});
```