# Filtering and counting values of array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{
date: "07-14-2022",
  report: [{
    vehicles: [{
      id: "uid",
      status: "active",
      type: "car"
    },
    {
      id: "uid",
      status: "oos",
      type: "bus"
    },
    {
      id: "uid",
      status: "pm",
      type: "bus"
    }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

I'm trying to achieve excluding any status other than "oos" or "pm" (was thinking about first using filter here for the first stage). And then I needed to group all the unique values for **type** so I could provide a breakdown of total numbers for each. So, in the end it would look like:

bus: 2

This is the first stage I was starting to work on, but having trouble...

```
  getReport() {
    this.backend.getAnalyticsReport().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(this.processReport(response))
      }
    )

    
  }

  processReport(obj: any) {
    return obj.filter((element: any) => this.filterStatus(element.vehicles))
  }

  filterStatus(element: any) {

    if (element.status === 'oos' || 'pm') { 
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

Comment: the correct condition would simply be `['oos', 'pm'].includes(element.status)`. the current condition will always be _truthy_, as it would evaluate to `'pm'` if the status isn't `'oos'`

Comment: or `element.status === 'oos' || element.status ===  'pm'`. see: [What's the prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/whats-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Comment: @Daniel what exactly does your `response` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` first then use `reduce` to group. This is a trick I've learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774906/3807365)

```js
var data = [{
    id: "uid",
    status: "active",
    type: "car"
  },
  {
    id: "uid",
    status: "oos",
    type: "bus"
  },
  {
    id: "uid",
    status: "pm",
    type: "bus"
  }
]

var result = data
  .filter(item => ['oos', 'pm'].indexOf(item.status) > -1)
  .reduce(function(agg, item) {
    agg[item.type] = (agg[item.type] || 0) + 1
    return agg;
  }, {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me -- because this object is within another object, I made this a function and called the method in a nested *ngFor loop  and then used the keyvalue pipe to display the keys as table header and the values as the cells. 

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using the `Array.reduce()` and `Array.includes()` methods. I modified the data to add in extra car calues that would be counted and added in an extra date to demonstrate how you could get the counts by day.

```js
const data = [{
    date: "07-14-2022",
    report: [{
      vehicles: [{
          id: "uid",
          status: "active",
          type: "car"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "oos",
          type: "bus"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "pm",
          type: "bus"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "pm",
          type: "car"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "active",
          type: "bus"
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    date: "07-15-2022",
    report: [{
      vehicles: [{
          id: "uid",
          status: "active",
          type: "car"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "oos",
          type: "car"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "pm",
          type: "bus"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "pm",
          type: "bus"
        },
        {
          id: "uid",
          status: "active",
          type: "bus"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];

const types = ["oos", "pm"];

const results = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.date] = c.report[0].vehicles.reduce((a2, c2) => {
    if (types.includes(c2.status)) {
      a2[c2.type] ??= 0;
      a2[c2.type]++;
    }
    return a2;
  }, {})
  return a
}, {});

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = JSON.stringify(results, null, 3);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```