# How to reduce multiple OR conditions in if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a condition:

```
if (item == 'a' || item == 'b' || item == 'c' || item == 'd' || item == 'e') {
    // statements
}
```

How can I reduce the branching? Is there any other way to write this in JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by branching?

Comment: What's `else` part here?

Comment: Can use switch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: sorry....updated the question.

Comment: `if('abcde'.indexof(item) >-1)...`

Comment: Here is a good post I think might already answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430000/determine-if-string-is-in-list-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the newer [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if (['a','b','c','d','e'].includes(item)) {
  ...
}
```

Another option (for the very specific case you posted) would be to compare unicode point values using `<`/`>`

```
if (item >= 'a' && item <= 'e') {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Word of caution, `Array.includes` is not supported on [IE11 or Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) although a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) can include it.

Comment: @QZSupport Array.includes is actually [supported in Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/arrayprototypeincludeses2016/?q=includes) (not in IE11 though). Thanks for noting that! :)

Comment: thanks, [updated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 5):

Use **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method with an array.

```
if(['a','b','c','d','e'].indexOf(item) > -1){
   //.........statements......
}
```

Comment: It does reduce the code length but not the branching at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array as shown below.

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
if(arr.indexOf(item) > -1) 
{
   //statements
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work nicely:

```
if('abcde'.indexOf(item) > -1) {
    ...
}
```

You could also use the newer [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), supported in ES6.

```
if('abcde'.includes(item)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: if item is `ab` ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan If it's `ab`, he'll use your answer. His example doesn't show `ab` so I would assume he doesn't require that functionality. kk :D